# What is the Grails equivalent of Rspec's let?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, rspec

Coming from Rails, I am having a hard time with unit tests in Grails. What is the equivalent of the following in in Grails?

`let(:some_variable) { SomeObject.new(name: 'Blabla', ...) }`

I want to define some variables that may be used in each test. Furthermore, I would like the objects to be saved, like:

```
def "some test"() {
    // given variable1 and variable2

    then:
    response.json.size() == 2
}
```

So the test would have two variables and the response would yield an array of those two objects, with size 2.

Comment: You mentioned about variables and response, but what operation you are seeking is missing in the question. Can you elaborate more on the question?

Answer (score 1):

Simple case:

```
@TestFor(SomeController)
class SomeControllerSpec extends Specification {
    def "some test"() {
        given:
            def var1 = new SomeObject(name:"AAA").save(flush:true)
            def var2 = new SomeObject(name:"BBB").save(flush:true)
        when:
            controller.someAction() 
            // assuming someAction fetches the SomeObject instances 
            // and marshals a JSON Response
        then:
            controller.response.json.size() == 2
    }
}
```

or perhaps:

```
@TestFor(SomeController)
class SomeControllerSpec extends Specification {

    // var1 and var2 are saved to the DB, and persist across all
    // the tests in this specification
    def var1 = new SomeObject(name:"AAA").save(flush:true)
    def var2 = new SomeObject(name:"BBB").save(flush:true)

    def "some test"() {
        when:
            controller.someAction() 
        then:
            controller.response.json.size() == 2
    }
}
```

Comment: But `let` allows you to reuse this implementation across tests. This seems like you need to repeat it in every example.

Comment: Or place that action in the setup() phase of the specification.  There are setup() and cleanup() methods available as well. Check the Grails docs section on testing.

Comment: You should edit your answer. And let has memoization, creates object only once then returns it, instead of returning new instance every time.